# tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory() can't find images exception

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following code to read jpeg images from a directory:

```
data_dir_str = "./photo/pults/samsung_small"
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir_str)
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*.*')))
print('images in directory: ' + str(image_count)) # 12 files in directory

sams_pults = list(data_dir.glob('*.jpg'))
img = PIL.Image.open(str(sams_pults[0]))
img_width, img_height = img.size
#img.show()  # This works well - shows image

batch_size = 10

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir_str, #data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  #seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size
)
```

Even though`img.show()` can display the images, `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory()` gives me the error:

> No images found in directory {directory}. Allowed formats:
> {ALLOWLIST_FORMATS}

Comment: There are all filenames look like 'photo_0.jpg',  'photo_1.jpg', ...

Comment: I have also tried to set all options to 'None': ```batch_size = 10

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=None,  #0.8,
  subset=None, #"training",
  seed=None,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

`./photo/pults/samsung_small` -> `./photo/pults`

The path needs to be set not as a dir where images are placed but one level above. Because the dir name is used for classification.

Answer (score 1):

If the directory contains just the images without subfolders for labels, then set the `label_mode=None` and the function will read the images as a dataset without labels.

e.g.

```py
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir_str, #data_dir,
  label_mode=None,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  #seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size
)
```